# Prove the complement $A-B$ is countable if $A$ is uncountable and $B$ is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

B is a countable subset of $A$.
Here's what I have:
$A-B$ with elements that are in $A$ but not in $B$.

$A$ is uncountable, so infinite. Take $k$ in $B$ as the largest element in finite $B$. $k$ is also in $A$, since $B$ is a subset of $A$. $k+1$ is in $A$ and not in $B$. $k+2$ is also in $A$ since $A$ in infinite, hence $A-B$ is uncountable.

Does this make sense? I am new to proofs and this made sense to me. We are learning about countable/uncountable sets so maybe I need to use different terminology? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Hello! I recommend reviewing the definitions of “countable” and “uncountable.” In particular, recall that *not every countable set is finite*. The correct definition of “countable” has to do with bijections, which is key to solving this problem.

Comment: I don't think this question should have been closed for lack of context.  It's probably a dupe, but the context appears adequate to me.

Answer (score 2):

The proof is wrong. The statement is also wrong. Counterexample is $A=\mathbb{R}$ and $B=\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Yes and according to the statement $A-B=\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ must be countable.